# Фигура поверх картинки tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, canvas, pillow

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
root=Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
canv=Canvas(root,highlightthickness=0)
canv.place(relwidth=1,relheight=1)
image=Image.open('Image.jpg')
image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label=Label(canv,image=image)
label.place(relwidth=1,relheight=1)
canv.create_oval(5,5,105,105,fill='red')
root.mainloop()
```

Я хочу,чтобы кружок был поверх изображения,но Label всегда выходит на первый план,закрывая собой круг.Сделать это нужно именно с помощью Canvas,а не с помощью метода paste класса PIL.Image например.

Comment: canvas.create_image() не подойдёт ?

Comment: Подойдёт,спасибо